# ubuntu boot fail: ACPI Region does not cover the entire command/response buffer

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi, firmware, tpm

So... unfortunately I can't boot on my ubuntu. This error suddenly came to me today while booting.

```
[     0.409100] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xda1d4000-0xda1d4fff flags 0x200] vs daid4000 4000
[     0.409117] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xda1d8000-0xda1d8fff flags 0x200] vs da1d8000 4000
```

I also tried to disable tpm, but it didn't solved.

Can someone help me at this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and it used to work before? What changed recently? Did you make any modifications in the BIOS or any updates or smth?

Comment: also you can try disabling fast boot in BIOS

Comment: @Esther also tried to disable it. And I did not change anything recently... it's really weird